A Stieltjes integral identity from Ivic's book Chapter 1 to prove the Laurent expansion of zeta
I am reading the proof of Theorem 1.3 of Aleksandar Ivic's book on Riemann zeta function. The part I am stuck on is an identity involving a Stieltje's integral
$$\tag{0}\label{S}S_r(x) := \sum_{n \leq x} n^{-1} (\log(x / n))^r = \int_{1-}^x t^{-1} \log^r(x/t) d [t].$$
At the 3rd last line of page 5, he claims that
$$\tag{1}\label{grz}\int_1^\infty t^{-s} dS_r(t) = r \int_1^\infty t^{-s-1}S_{r-1}(t)dt.$$
I was able to show this for $r = 1$. First by differentiating \eqref{S} with respect to $x$ in both the integral upper bound and integrand, and noticing that the partial derivative with respect to the integral upper bound vanishes, we have
$$dS_1(x) = \int_{1-}^x t^{-1} \frac{t}{x} \frac{1}{t} d[t] = \int_{1-}^x \frac{1}{tx} d[t] = \frac1x \sum_{u=1}^x u^{-1},$$
since $r = 1$. Therefore
$$\tag{2}\label{lhs}\int_1^\infty t^{-s} dS_1(t) = \int_1^\infty t^{-s} t^{-1} \sum_{u \leq t} u^{-1} dt.$$
On the other hand, the right hand side of \eqref{grz} evaluates to
$$\tag{3}\label{rhs}\int_1^\infty t^{-s-1}\sum_{u \leq t} u^{-1} dt.$$
So we see that \eqref{lhs} and \eqref{rhs} are the same.

Perhaps it helps to note that for $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$$ the transform $$F(s)=s, \mathcal{M}xf(x)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f(x), x^{-s-1} , dx=\sum\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$$ can also be evaluated as $$F(s)=\mathcal{M}xf'(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty f'(x), x^{-s} , dx=\sum\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$$.

@StevenClark Thank you. I think for $r = 1$ I made a mistake. Will update the calculation.

My mistake was in basic derivative calculation:
earlier I thought
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log^r\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) = \log^{r-1} \left(\frac{x}{t} \right)\frac{1}{x},$$
in fact I missed differentiating $\log$ itself, so it should be
$$\frac{d}{dx} \log^r\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) = \log^{r-1} \left(\frac{x}{t} \right)\frac{t}{x}\frac{1}{x}.$$
Thus we have
$$\begin{aligned}
dS_r(x) &= \int_{1-}^x t^{-1} r \log^{r-1}\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)\frac{t}{x}\frac{1}{t}d[t] \\
&= \sum_{u=1}^x (ux)^{-1}r\log^{r-1}\left(\frac{x}{u}\right),
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_1^\infty t^{-s} dS_r(t) &= r \int_1^\infty t^{-s} \sum_{u=1}^t u^{-1}t^{-1} \log^{r-1}\left(\frac{t}{u}\right) dt \\
&=r \int_1^\infty t^{-s-1}\sum_{u=1}^t u^{-1} \log^{r-1}\left(\frac{t}{u}\right)dt = r \int_1^\infty t^{-s-1} S_{r-1}(t)dt,
\end{aligned}$$
the last equality by noticing that
$$S_r(x) = \sum_{u=1}^x u^{-1} \log^r\left(\frac{x}{u}\right).$$
The only thing that remains fishy is the following claim
Let $T_r(x, y) := \int_{1-}^x t^{-1}\log^r\left(\frac{y}{t}\right) d[t]$, so that $S_r(x) = T_r(x, x)$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx}S_r(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}T_r(x, y)\rvert_{y=x} + \frac{d}{dy}T_r(x, y)|_{y=x} \\
&= 0 + \frac{r}{x} \int_{t=1}^x t^{-1} \log^{r-1}\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) dt.
\end{aligned}
$$
To justify $\frac{d}{dx} T_r(x, y)|_{y=x} = 0$, notice that $T_r(x+\epsilon, x) - T_r(x - \epsilon, x) = 0$.
It's interesting that even though the definition of $S_r(x)$ looks discrete in $x$, it in fact is differentiable and even smooth, thanks to the appearance of $x$ in the defining integrand, and the 0 integrand value at $t=x$.
